# Volume Control keys duplicating on key press

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, samsung, volume-control

For some odd reason, when I use my FN Volume control keys on my laptop, Ubuntu duplicates the input infinitely until I interrupt it by putting a window in full screen. I'm not sure why it's doing this and searching the internet has found nothing aside form similar questions with no answer. This happens with My mute, Volume Up and Volume Down. If I press it once, Ubuntu repeats it infinitely with the OSD flickering. An answer would be awesome as I can't use those keys at the moment. If more info is needed, just ask and I'll see what I can do.

Samsung Notebook, Model NP355E7C-A01US
Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, sound would go crazy if I clicked volume up,down or mute button.

The solution that worked for me is rather simple. Just go to **System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Sound and Media** and edit volume up,down and mute settings again to FN + up,down and mute keys on your keyboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a really old thread but this worked for me with ubuntu 20.0.4. settings > keyboard > "view and customize keyboard shortcuts" > then manually map the laptop media function keys to their appropriate function. it used to be that pressing volume up or down would cause the volume to go all the way to max or mute and it was driving me crazy.